# Flashcard app that supports freehand drawings?

Tags: android, educational, drawing

There are dozens of flashcards study applications for Android. However, the most lack of the possibility to add freehand drawings to a flashcard on the device. I'm looking for a good app that provides this feature. The recognition and special treatment of S-Pens usage would be a great extra.

Comment: We are doing our best to add this feature to AnkiDroid asap :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Glad to hear, I am very much looking forward to (an early simple solution, later replaced or supplemented by a more complex implementation?). I hope you have the opportunity to take a closer look at S-Note and Papyrus for inspiration.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Has this been added yet?

Comment: @ṧнʊß: Not yet... looking for volunteer developers as we are busy with bug-fixing and other features :-)